Problem with uv autocompletion in Fish shell after activating Mise
I’m trying to set up autocompletion for uv in Fish shell while using Mise to manage my environment. Mise has been installed correctly, and I'm using Fish as my terminal shell. However, autocompletion for uv isn't working, and I can’t seem to figure out how to fix it.

I installed Mise using the following command:

curl https://mise.run | sh


I installed uv within Mise:

mise use -g uv


I attempted to configure the autocompletion for uv by adding the following to my ~/.config/fish/config.fish file, like the documentation:

echo 'uv generate-shell-completion fish | source' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish


Issue: When I open the terminal i get the following error:

Command 'uv' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install astral-uv
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 6):
uv generate-shell-completion fish | source
^^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup

Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type help for instructions on how to use fish

Additional Info:

Ubuntu 24.04 (WSL-2)
Windows 11
Windows Terminal

My config.fish:
if status is-interactive
    # Commands to run in interactive sessions can go here
end

~/.local/bin/mise activate fish | source
uv generate-shell-completion fish | source

What am I doing wrong in setting up autocompletion for uv in Fish shell with Mise?
Is there any additional configuration or step I need to perform for autocompletion to work correctly?
